# Exists any way to use Expression Web 4 with Subversion?

Tags: asp.net, expression-web

Does anyone know any workaround to use Expression Web 4 with Subversion's repositories? I'm currently using Ankhsvn plugin for VS, it works like a charm but i don't get how this can be used with EW.

I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: You can vote up AnkhSVN here for an implementation in blend. http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/forums/3267-ankhsvn-general/suggestions/547499-expression-blend-3-support

Comment: Yeah, that would be great. It's done, i already vote. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure, but you could try VisualSVN. I used to use that, now use AnkhSVN, but VisualSVN has support for expression blend (apparently)

http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/
http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/

> VisualSVN is now compatible with
>   Microsoft Expression Blend.

It does cost however.

Edit:

Looking at the AnkhSVN feedback:

http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/forums/3267-ankhsvn-general/suggestions/547499-expression-blend-3-support?ref=title

Might be worth a comment and vote on that.

Comment: yea, this thing has been there for months now. Probably a few more votes (get over 100+) will get their attention.

Comment: Hi Phill, thanks for your response. Do you know if VisualSVN has support for all the Expression Suite? (because i'm interested in EW at this time) or just for Blend?

Comment: @elvin - To be honest I've never actually looked at EW, I've played with Blend and am aware it has support for source control. I made the assumption that EW would have support for source control too in-which case it might work with EW. You can download VisualSVN on a trial basis to test it.

Comment: @elvin - http://dumians.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/team-foundation-server-support-in-expression-web-3/ this says TFS is supported, so assuming the provider required for blend is the same for web, then VisualSVN should work. Download the trial and give it a test.

Comment: Good point @Phill, i will try it out, looks like my best option. Thanks again.